# Include django rest pandas dataframe Index field in json response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

## Backgroud

I am using django-rest-pandas for serving json & xls.

## Observation

When I hit url with format=xls, I get complete data in the downloaded file. But for format=josn, the index field of dataframe is not part of the records.

## Question

How can I make django-rest-pandas to include dataframe's index field in json response? 
*Note that the index field is present as part of serializer (extending serializer.ModelSerializer).*

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to just reset the index in transform_dataframe method.

df = df.reset_index()

This would just add a new index and set your old index as a column, included in the output.